# first time save blank page using webivew in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, webview

I have `local html file` i want to save the html to loaded `Webview` in local path. 
But first time always save empty data.

```
 try 
        {
            htmltopdfs = html;
            var dir = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/SVSTATIONERY/");
            var file = new Java.IO.File(dir + "/" + fileName + ".pdf");

            if (!dir.Exists())
                dir.Mkdirs();
            //else
            //    dir.Delete();

            int x = 0;
            while (file.Exists())
            {
                x++;
                file = new Java.IO.File(dir + "/" + fileName + "( " + x + " )" + ".pdf");
            }

            //if (webpage == null)
            var webpage = new Android.Webkit.WebView(MainActivity.context);

            int width = 2102;
            int height = 2970;

            webpage.Layout(0, 0, width, height);
            webpage.LoadDataWithBaseURL("", htmltopdfs, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            webpage.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewCallBack(file.ToString()));

            return file.ToString();
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
```

`Onpagefinished event`

```
 class WebViewCallBack : WebViewClient
{

    string fileNameWithPath = null;

    public WebViewCallBack(string path)
    {
        this.fileNameWithPath = path;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView myWebview, string url)
    {
        PdfDocument document = new Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.StartPage(new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(2102, 3500, 1).Create());

        myWebview.Draw(page.Canvas);
        document.FinishPage(page);
        Stream filestream = new MemoryStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(fileNameWithPath, false);

        document.WriteTo(filestream);
        fos.Write(((MemoryStream)filestream).ToArray(), 0, (int)filestream.Length);
        fos.Close();
    }


}
```

> After Creating, but first time, blank page has been created to the local path, after then creating multiple times its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my demo about printting webview(load the local html) to PDF.

Here is running GIF().

[image]

My layout in xamarin forms like following code.

```
   <StackLayout>
    <Button Text="save" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <Entry x:Name="MyEntry" Text="5"></Entry>
    <Label x:Name="MyLabel"></Label>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <WebView x:Name="MywebView" HeightRequest="1000" Navigated="MywebView_Navigated"
    WidthRequest="1000"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In the Android achievement, I used MessagingCenter and custom renderer for webview to achieve that.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyWebviewRender))]
```

namespace MyWebView.Droid
{
    class MyWebviewRender : WebViewRenderer
    {
        Context context;
        public MyWebviewRender(Context context) : base(context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "pdf", (key) => {

            var printManager = (PrintManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PrintService);
            var printAdapter = new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(context, Control);
            var printJob = printManager.Print("MyPrintJob", printAdapter, null);

        });


    }

}
```

`MyPrintDocumentAdapter.cs`

```
    public class MyPrintDocumentAdapter : PrintDocumentAdapter
{

    View view;
    Context context;
    PrintedPdfDocument document;
    float scale;

    public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(Context context, View view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override void OnLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras)
    {
        document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);

        CalculateScale(newAttributes);

        //set the printed PDF attributes
        var printInfo = new PrintDocumentInfo
            .Builder("MyPrint.pdf")
            .SetContentType(PrintContentType.Document)
            .SetPageCount(10)
            .Build();

        callback.OnLayoutFinished(printInfo, true);
    }

    public override void OnWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback)
    {
        PrintedPdfDocument.Page page = document.StartPage(0);

        page.Canvas.Scale(scale, scale);

        view.Draw(page.Canvas);

        document.FinishPage(page);

        WritePrintedPdfDoc(destination);

        document.Close();

        document.Dispose();

        callback.OnWriteFinished(pages);
    }

    void CalculateScale(PrintAttributes newAttributes)
    {
        int dpi = Math.Max(newAttributes.GetResolution().HorizontalDpi, newAttributes.GetResolution().VerticalDpi);

        int leftMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.LeftMils / 1000);
        int rightMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.RightMils / 1000);
        int topMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.TopMils / 1000);
        int bottomMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.BottomMils / 1000);

        int w = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.GetMediaSize().WidthMils / 1000) - leftMargin - rightMargin;
        int h = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.GetMediaSize().HeightMils / 1000) - topMargin - bottomMargin;

        scale = Math.Min((float)document.PageContentRect.Width() / w, (float)document.PageContentRect.Height() / h);
    }

    void WritePrintedPdfDoc(ParcelFileDescriptor destination)
    {
        var i=destination.FileDescriptor;
        var javaStream = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(destination.FileDescriptor);
        var osi = new OutputStreamInvoker(javaStream);
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            document.WriteTo(mem);
            var bytes = mem.ToArray();
            osi.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my demo link.
https://github.com/851265601/PrintLocalWebview2PDF

Comment: @Vignesh Siva  Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.